# Are non-latin numerals in Windows SBCS codepages used by any Microsoft libraries to represent numerical data in C strings?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, codepages, data-conversion

I'm trying to write a parser for "text" files which I know will be encoded in one of the [Windows single byte code pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654). These files contain text representations of basic data types, and the spec I have for these representations is lacking, to say the least.

I noticed in [Windows-874](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305142) ten little inconspicuous characters near the end called `THAI DIGIT ZERO` to `THAI DIGIT NINE`.

I'm trying to write this parser to be pretty robust but I'm working a bit in the dark as there are many different programs which can generate these data files and I don't have access to the sources.

What I want to know is: **do any functions in Microsoft C++ libraries convert real number data types into a `std::string` or `char const *` (i.e. serialization) which would contain non-[arabic-numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals)**?

I don't use Microsoft C++ libraries so can't reference any in particular but a made-up example could be `char const * IntegerFunctions::ToString(int i)`.

Comment: Windows internally uses Unicode (UTF-16); pretty much all SBCS and MBCS support is implemented by converting to and from Unicode. (The exception being very trivial functions like `strcpy`).

Comment: It does now but hasn't always ;) my data files can come from any time period in the last ~15 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These digits certainly could be created by Microsoft libraries. The properties `LOCALE_IDIGITSUBSTITUTION` and `LOCALE_SNATIVEDIGITS` determine whether numbers formatted by the OS will use native (i.e. non-ASCII) digits. Those are initially Unicode, because that's what how Windows internally creates strings. When you have a Thai locale, and you convert Unicode to CP874, then those characters will be kept.

A simple function that demonstrates this behavior is [`GetNumberFormatA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that `GetNumberFormat` would be more for translation (i.e. arabic-numeral `string` to non-arabic-numeral `string`)? And it's therefore reasonable to assume no one would do this for serialization of a data type in a file which isn't meant to be hand modified? I'm essentially trying to predict what kind of number representations I am likely to encounter.

Comment: It works both ways; i.e. you can use it to check how `"42.7"` would look in Thai digits. Any other Windows function that formats 42.7 into a string for human consumption (i.e. using the user's locale) will also apply LOCALE_IDIGITSUBSTITUTION and LOCALE_SNATIVEDIGITS.

Comment: And what options do you have for acknowledging/ignoring locale: none, set-once, or per-call?

Comment: Depends on the function. There's always a user locale, but some functions ignore it (especially in the kernel - no user context), some use the default, and some allow you to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of the inverse answer, but [this page](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/download.php?f=str_to_int_unicode.html) seems to indicate that Microsoft's runtime libraries at understand quite a few (but not all) non-Latin numerals when doing what you want to do, i.e. parse a string into a number.

Thai is included, which seems to indicate that it's a good idea to support it in custom code, too.

To include more information here, the linked-to page states that Microsoft's `msvcr100` runtime supports decoding numerals from the following character sets:

- ASCII
- Arabic-Indic
- Extended Arabic
- Devanagari
- Bengali
- Gurmukhi
- Gujarati
- Oriya
- Telugu
- Kannada
- Malayalam
- Thai
- Lao
- Tibetan
- Myanmar
- Khmer
- Mongolian
- Full Width

The full page includes more programming environments and more languages (there are plenty of negatives, too).

Comment: Sorry, upon re-reading your answer, it appears you've answered the inverse routine of what I'm asking. I've updated the question to clarify.